# private static member function vs private member function

Tags: c++, static

One can choose public static over private static if the static needs to be accessed outside the class(e.g. singleton), while private static is preferred when the function need not be exposed(otherwise unnamed namespaces would do fine) - in which case its only access either through static member function or other non static member functions

However i am trying to get to the core idea of why would one choose private static over private member function? 
Ofcourse, both can have access to private members of the class(or any object that is passed), with static member explicitly requiring an object to be passed, but why can't i keep my design open by making it a private Non-Static member function even if it doesn't need access to private members(just like static member functions). This way even if in future i require to access some private members i save myself from converting static to non-static mem func - I understand this isn't a big deal/change but still can somebody give me a crystal clear idea about when and why to choose one over the other?

Comment: Non-static member function need to pass an additional _pointer-to-instance_ argument, which represents some overhead. In some performance-critical apps, this overhead might matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `static` member variable, you choose its access level in just the same way that you would for a non-`static` member variable. There's nothing "special" here.

Most of my private `static`s tend to be things like built-in constants that are only used by the internals of the class.

I admit I can't think of many other use cases for them, but I will also tend to make *any* function `static` if it logically has nothing to do with a particular instance of the class (and thus needs no non-static member access) — this may be a bit more OCD than some people indulge in though.

> why can't i keep my design open by making it a private Non-Static member function even if it doesn't need access to private members(just like static member functions)

You can. It is up to you.

> This way even if in future i require to access some private members i save myself from converting static to non-static mem func

Sure. I mean, it's *one* keyword. But this "forward-compatibility" may be useful if you need to keep your headers from changing (e.g. you're deploying them). Arguably this is a downside of making `static` members private, where there aren't really many solid upsides. Again, it's up to you.